# Performance comparison: 64 bit and 32 bit multiplication

Tags: c, performance, cpu, cpu-registers

I'm using an *Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz* and wondering why the multiplication of 64 bit numbers is slower than that of 32 bit numbers. I've done a test run in C and it turns out it needs twice as much time.

I expected it to need the same amount of time since the CPU works with native 64 bit registers and it shouldn't matter how wide the numbers are (as long as they fit into a 64 bit register).

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling as 64-bit?

Comment: @Boann Most processors implementing x86-64 will still have faster 32-bit multiplication. See e.g. page 12 in http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf for one difference in timing between 32- and 64-bit IMUL.

Comment: @Boann Wrong page! (that was for an old processor where multiplication only went to 32-bit. It was still faster than 16-bit multiplication though). Try page 22 for 64-bit vs 32-bit IMUL on a processor implementing x86-64.

Comment: Modern cores are ridiculously fast.  But that's not the typical constraint in a program, those fast cores have to deal with ridiculously slow memory.  There's some expectation that you move twice as much data around when you use 64-bit multiplies, that's of course going to be twice as slow when the true bottleneck is memory.  There, quicky explanation, there are plenty more.  There's no point in not showing your code so you can get an *accurate* answer instead of a guess.

Comment: Better show the assembly code. Also, a modern CPU might well be able to process two 32 bit operations on parallel when it gets the chance, using the same logic circuitry it would be using for a single 64 bit operation.

Comment: it was the memory. I read the numbers from huge arrays on the heap. This, as explained in the comment from Hans, lasts twice as long for larger integers. Without reading the numbers from memory (instead generating them from random) the difference is much much smaller. The remaining difference might be due to the fact that calculations on 32 bit instead of 64 bit registers are up to one or two cycles faster. Thanks a lot for all comments and answers.

Answer (score 7):

There are specialized instructions in the x86-64 instruction set to express that you only want to multiply two `32-bit` quantities. One instruction may look like `IMUL %EBX, %ECX` in a particular dialect for the x86-64 assembly, as opposed to the 64-bit multiplication `IMUL %RBX, %RCX`.

So the processor knows that you only want to multiply 32-bit quantities. This happens often enough that the designers of the processor made sure that the internal circuitry would be optimized to provide a faster answer in this easier case, just as it is easier for you to multiply 3-digit numbers than 6-digit numbers. The difference can be seen in the timings measured by Agner Fog and described in his [comprehensive assembly optimization resources](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

If your compiler is targeting the older 32-bit IA-32 instruction set, then the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit multiplication is even wider. The compiler has to implement 64-bit multiplication with only instructions for 32-bit multiplication, using four of them (three if computing only the 64 least significant bits of the result).
64-bit multiplication can be about three-four times slower than 32-bit multiplication in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a problem occuring here because of 64-bit multiplication.

Actually, for multiplying two 32-bit numbers,the result will be maximum of 64 bits. But, in case of multiplying two 64-bit numbers, the product may be of 128 bits and in all cases it'll be greater than 64 bits!

As a similar example in 8086 microprocessor,if you'll perform the same with 8-bit numbers and 16-bit numbers,you'll encounter the situation that CPU registers will have to store it from AX register and DX register as well(if you know the assembly language abbreviations).

So,I believe that is possibly increasing the calculation time!!! I feel this is what making your 64-bits multiplication slow!

Comment: Guess is not an answer, perhaps this should have been a comment.

Comment: AX and DX are 16-bit registers. And it is certainly _not_ true that all 64-bit multiplies produce 128 significant bits in the result.  The 2 and 3 operand mul instructions throw away high order bits.

Comment: AX and DX are 16-bit but their counterpart in x86_64 system might be having the same situation. It seems I forgot to mention about 8086 system,this example I gave was for 8086 microprocessor! I am adding it.THANKS!

Comment: @Gene- My answer already had that previously too that not all 64-bit multiplications are 128 bit long,but,certainly greater than 64 bit!